# Last letters remove form array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I want to remove the last few letters from an array in a for-each loop. I am trying to show `bl_date` without `/2018`. Now its showing `07/10/2018 & 06/30/2018`. How can echo like this `07/10 & 06/30`?

**Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [bl_user] => 61
            [bl_date] => 07/10/2018
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [bl_user] => 61
            [bl_date] => 06/30/2018

        )

)
```

**PHP**

```
$resultstr = array();
foreach ($billings as $billing) {
  $resultstr[] = $billing->bl_date;
}
echo implode(" & ",$resultstr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `substr()` to remove the last 5 characters of the string

Like:

```
$resultstr = array();
foreach ($billings as $billing) {
  $resultstr[] = substr( $billing->bl_date, 0, -5 );
}
echo implode(" & ",$resultstr);
```

This will result to:

```
07/10 & 06/30
```

Doc: [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use substr function:

```
foreach ($billings as $billing) {
  $resultstr[] = substr($billing->bl_date, 0, 5);
}
```